# How to use a list of aggregate expressions with groupby in pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, pyspark, aggregate

I have a dataframe with 2 columns like this:

```
+----+---+
|ptyp|sID|
+----+---+
|  CO|111|
|  CO|222|
|  CO|222|
|  CO|222|
|  CO|111|
|  CD|111|
|  CD|222|
|  CD|222|
|  CD|333|
|  CD|333|
|  CD|333|
|  AG|111|
|  AG|111|
|  AG|111|
|  AG|222|
+----+---+
```

Given an input `n`, for each `pytp`, I want to add columns which display the top `n` `sIDs` (in terms of number of times they appear for that `pytp`). I also want to print the number of times each `sID` occurs in a column `sIDval` for each group.

For example, if `n = 2`, I want the output to be like this:

```
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|ptyp|topSID1|topSID1_val|topSID2|topSID2_val|
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|  AG|    111|          3|    222|          1|
|  CO|    222|          3|    111|          2|
|  CD|    333|          3|    222|          2|
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

I am using `UDFs` to calculate this:

```
@F.udf
def mode(x, top_rank):
    c = Counter(x).most_common(top_rank)
    sz = len(c)
    return c[min(top_rank-1, sz-1)][0]

@F.udf
def modeval(x, top_rank):
    c = Counter(x).most_common(top_rank)
    sz = len(c)
    return c[min(top_rank-1, sz-1)][1]
```

And I am storing the aggregate expressions required for each new column in a list `newcols`:

```
newcols = []
n = 3

for r in range(1, num_ranks+1):
    newcols.append([mode(F.collect_list('sID'), F.lit(r)).alias('topSID' + str(r))])
    newcols.append([modeval(F.collect_list('sID'), F.lit(r)).alias('topSID' + str(r) +'_val')])
```

Now if I know that `n=3`, I can do it in this way:

```
df.groupBy('ptyp').agg(*newcols[0], *newcols[1], *newcols[2], \
                       *newcols[3], *newcols[4], *newcols[5])
```

Is there a way I can use generalize this for any value of `n`?
I tried

```
df.groupBy('ptyp').agg([*e for e in new_cols])
```

and

```
df.groupBy('ptyp').agg((*e for e in new_cols))
```

and many more variations, but all of them give errors.

Now I have resorted to aggregating one at a time and doing a join but that is very expensive.

Is there a way to do this in the manner I've tried above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension is the correct way to go, but you can't extract the sublists with `*` as they don't have a target. When you call:

```py
print(*newcols[0])
```

You get an output like:

```py
Column<b'mode(collect_list(sID, 0, 0), 1) AS `topSID1`'>
```

`newcols` is a list of list and you can flatten this list of list by using another list comprehension.

```py
print([item for sublist in newcols for item in sublist][0])
```

Which returns the same output:

```py
Column<b'mode(collect_list(sID, 0, 0), 1) AS `topSID1`'>
```

Therefore you can do the following to get the expected behavior:

```py
df.groupBy('ptyp').agg(*[item for sublist in newcols for item in sublist])
```